# How do I create custom regions on a world map, using jvectormap to display it?

Tags: jvectormap

I want to create 15 different regions that include one or more countries each. Each region will have a subset or all of the countries in a specific continent, e.g. Canada, US, Mexico will show as North America.
The goal is that when a user hover's over one of these custom regions, it will show the name that I have given that region.

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

JVectorMap not supported continent api.

and...I worked as follows.

// 1. You make continents. and

```
var continents = {};
continents['AF'] = 'Africa';
continents['AS'] = 'Asia';
continents['EU'] = 'Europe';
continents['NA'] = 'North-America';
```

etc...

// 2. make continents color

```
var styles = {};
style['AF'] = {fill: '#000000', stroke : '#000000', "stroke-width": 1};
style['AS'] = {styles['AS'] = {fill: '#FFFF00', stroke : '#000000', "stroke-width": 1};
```

etc...

Should be set continent. your self...